# Synchornized vs volatile which to use?

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, volatile

Please execuse me if this Quesiton is already posted. I couldn't find it.

In the following implementations, `getValue()` is read operation and `onDataChange()` is a write operation to the integer object. My question here is, readers usage is very high compared to writing usage. To be specific, writing happens once in a year where as reading occurs 100 times a day. Different and multiple threads will be involved for reading and even for writing too though it's usage is less. In such cases, which of the following implementations are better? I am preferring to use the volatile implementations, but would like to take your feedback. Please feel free to update me if there are issues with these implementations or better approach.

**1. Volatile usage :**

```
public class SingletonClass{
    private static SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
        private SingletonClass(){
    }

    private volatile Integer val = new Integer(3);

    public int getValue(){
        return val.toInteger();
    }
    public onDataChange(int value){
        this.val = new Integer(value);
    }
}
```

**2. Read - Write lock**

```
public class SingletonClass{

    private static SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
        private SingletonClass(){
    }
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
    private final Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    private Integer val = new Integer(3);

    public int getValue(){
        try{
         readLock.lock();
         return val.toInteger();
         } finally{
            readLock.unlock();
         }
     }

    public onDataChange(int value){
       try{
           writeLock.lock();
           this.val = new Integer(value);
       } finally{
           writeLock.unlock();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are just replacing the value (not increamenting), it is just fine to use volatile. The new value will be visible to other threads immediately, and no locking will be involved

Comment: I would simply use an AtomicInteger, which would lead to more readable code and express the intent clearly. If it's the performance that you're worried about, everything is fast enough when you read something only 100 times a day.

Comment: Thanks @Kamil.H for the reply. But I heard volatile reads are costlier  than normal variable reads. Since readers are high in number, I thought even volatile is costly. Do you too agree that volatile is better than locks in this case?

Comment: @NaveenPotnuru volatile read is close to a normal read. Volatile writes are more expensive but still a lot less than locking... BTW if performance is a concern why do you use a boxed primitive? As mentioned above just use an AtomicInteger.

Comment: @assylias Integer instance in the above sample is an example, it will be a diff class in my application.

Comment: @NaveenPotnuru at the scale of a computer, which does billions of operations per second, reading 100 times a day and writing once a day is ridiculously tiny. Don't worry about performance. Use what's the most readable.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right. But my application will be grabbing different parameters from one volatile object and also from different classes of similar structure. Some times, it goes crazy and pull these paramters more than 100 times probably 2000 times a day. In that case, I believe performance matters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but I would use [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) here, as it is perfectly suited for this use-case, i.e.

> An int value that may be updated atomically

```
private class SingletonClass {
    private static SingletonClass instance = new SingletonClass();
    private SingletonClass() {}

    private final AtomicInteger val = new AtomicInteger(3);

    public int getValue(){
        return this.val.get();
    }

    public onDataChange(int value){
        this.val.set(value);
    }
}
```